# Проблемы с сервером

Tags: веб-сервер, linux

Всем добрый день.

Кто-нибудь может помочь разобраться в проблеме?
Проблема следующая: в последнее время на моем сервере стали появляться левые папки, к которым нет доступа из фтп, а в файлах сайта стали появляться коды, которые при заходе на сайт перекидывают на рекламу. Права на файлы и папки стали меняться, а также стала сбиваться кодировка файлов. Кто знает, как с этим бороться и что это вообще такое?

Comment: @DreamChild, по-моему это вполне вопрос по системному администрированию. Я неправ?

Answer (score 1):

Это вирус. Возможно, вы добавляли на сайт, например, новые темы оформления. При их открытии запустился или сейчас постоянно запускается скрытый код, который насоздавал папок и изменил на них права. Открывайте каждый файл и смотрите функции типа eval(), их все надо удалить.

**Обновление**

Если не найдется, то стоит еще раз поискать повнимательнее. Возможно эти функции уже закачали код, который их удалил и разместил вместо них обычные Header(Location...). Хешкод не фриланс биржа, но смогу помочь, если обратитесь.

**Обновление 2**

Можно сохранить копию файла, удалить функцию и проверить работу сайта. Если что - восстановить копию. На что заменить неизвестные мне функции в неизвестном коде, советовать сложно. Да, и искать надо не только в js файлах, а в php коде тоже. При чем в коде php функции имеют доступ к изменению данных на сервере (что у вас и произошло).

Comment: А если подобных функций не найдется?

Comment: @alexsis20102, давайте вы сначала поищете, а потом, если не найдется, придете сюда с тем, что есть.

Comment: Нашел подобные функции в Javascrip файлах, таких как календарь Jquery и в нескольких файлах редактора Ckeditor, но удалять побоялся, вдруг работать перестанет, может, эти функции можно заменить на что-либо? Что посоветуете?

Comment: Обновил ответ